# Python3: How to convert plain html into nested dictionary based on level of `h` tags?

Tags: python, dictionary, beautifulsoup, nested, tuples

I have a html that looks like this:

```
<h1>Sanctuary Verses</h1>
    <h2>Purpose and Importance of the Sanctuary</h2>
       <p>Ps 73:17\nUntil I went into the sanctuary of God; [then] understood I their end.</p>
       <p>...</p>
    <h2>Some other title</h2>
        <p>...</p>
         <h3>sub-sub-title</h3>
             <p>sub-sub-content</p>
    <h2>Some different title</h2>
        <p>...</p>...
```

There are no `div` or `section` tags that group the `p` tags. It works well for display purposes. I want to extract data such that I get the desired output.

Desired Output:

1. The `h` tags should be displayed as titles and nested according to their levels
2. The `p` tags should be added to the contents under the specific title as given by the `h` tag

### Desired Output:

```
{
  "title": "Sanctuary Verses"
  "contents": [
    {"title": "Purpose and Importance of the Sanctuary"
     "contents":["Ps 73:17\nUntil I went into the sanctuary of God; [then] understood I their end.",
                 "...."
                ]
    },
    {"title": "Some other title"
     "contents": ["...",
                 {"title": "sub-sub-title"
                  "content": ["sub-sub-content"]
                 }
                 ]
    },
    {"title": "Some different title"
     "content": ["...","..."]
    }
}
```

I had written some workaround code that helped me get the desired output. I am wondering which is the easiest way to get the desired output

Comment: What is the output you are expecting. Are we doing dictionaries inside of dictionaries with recursion based on the html tags ? like `versesDict = {
    'Sanctuary Verses': {
        'Purpose and Importance of the Sanctuary':
            '>Ps 73:17\nUntil I went into the sanctuary of God; [then] understood I their end.'
    }
}`

Comment: @SamuelMiddendorp I have added the desired output

Comment: why you decide "Purpose.." as h2 but "Ps..." as p ? They both have (2,2) so they are supposed to be siblings, right ?

Comment: h2 is a heading tag in html right? The data was supposed to be nested. But for display purpose was made into siblings. I need to nest the data, hence the question

Comment: @OneFace Something to think about, a dictionary consists of keys and values. Whenever you wanna extract a value you have to query the key. To me it seems as tho the dictionary would function alot better if the key would be the title of the document and the value would be its children. H1 being the parent and its contents being the H2's inside. This way if you wanted to query all the subverses(I am probally butchering some terminology here, sorry for that) You could just do `print(versesDict['Sanctuary Verses'])`.

Comment: @SamuelMiddendorp I have modified the question to add clarity

Comment: If there is a better way to extract the data such that it will be easier to make into a dictionary, I would be very happy to know

Comment: @matt the output is very large and I have just shown a sample. I have added more details regarding the second index and how I use it. The full output is here:https://pastebin.com/waxkRBrV

Comment: Full Input is here: https://pastebin.com/j5we9TCr

Comment: I have added the output for the sample html given at the top. `p` should be in the `content` list of the dictionary. I am trying to make it into a `title`, `content` dictionary where the title is the `h` tag and the content contains all the `p` tags under that title as a list. I want to nest the dictionary just like the html is nested @matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of a stack problem/graph problem. Lets call it a tree. (or document or whatever.)

I think your initial tuple could be improved. (text, depth, type)

```
stack = []
depth = 0
broken_value = -1
current = {"title":"root", "contents":[]}
for item in list_of_tuples:
    if item[1]>depth:
         #deeper
         next = { "title":item[0], "contents":[]  }
         current["contents"].append(next)
         stack.append(current)
         current=next
         depth = item[1]
    elif item[1]<depth:
         #shallower closes current gets previous level
         while depth>item[1]:
             prev = stack.pop()
             depth = depth-1
         current = {"title":item[0], "content":[]}
         stack[-1].append(current)
         depth=item[1]
    else:
         #same depth 
         if item[2]==broken_value:
             #<p> element gets added to current level.
             current['contents'].append(item[0])
         else:
             #<h> element gets added to parent of current.
             current = {"title":item[0], "content":[]}
             stack[-1]["contents"].append(current)
    broken_value = item[2]
```

This would create an arbitrary depth graph that assumes the depth increases by 1 but
could decrease by an arbitrary number.

It would probably be best to keep track of the depth in the dictionary so that you can move more than one depth at a time. Instead of just "title" and "content" maybe "title", "depth", and "content"

**Explanation**
The stack keeps track of open elements, and our current element is the element we are building.

If we find a depth > than our current depth, then we put the current element on the stack (it is still open) and start working on the next level element.

If the depth is less than the current element, we will close the current element and parent elements up to the same depth.

Finally if it is the same depth, we decide if it is a 'p' element that just gets added, or another 'h' that closes the current and starts a new current.

Comment: `prev = stack.pop()` would this not remove the last element of `stack` instead of closing it?

Comment: @OneFace that is what I mean by closing it. stack keeps all of the open elements sorted by depth. So if our depth is currently 3, and the next element is 2, we need to remove the last element in the stack, presumable at depth 2, which "closes it" since it is no longer in our list of open items.

Comment: There was a couple of errors:`current.append(i[0])` had to be changed to `current['contents'].append(i[0])`. I had to use http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html# to understand that there was more than one element in the `stack` and that is how you had kept it open. But this is an awesome piece of code! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion with `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools as it, re
def to_tree(d):
  v, r = [list(b) for _, b in it.groupby(d, key=lambda x:not x[0])], []
  for i in v:
    if r and isinstance(r[-1], dict) and not r[-1]['content']:
      r[-1]['content'] = to_tree([(j[4:], k) for j, k in i])
    else:
      for _, k in i:
        r.append(re.sub('</*\w+\>', '', k) if not re.findall('^\<h', k) else {'title':re.sub('</*\w+\>', '', k), 'content':[]})
  return r
```

---

```
import json
result = to_tree([((lambda x:'' if not x else x[0])(re.findall('^\s+', i)), re.sub('^\s+', '', i)) for i in filter(None, html.split('\n'))])
print(json.dumps(result[0], indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
   "title": "Sanctuary Verses",
   "content": [
    {
        "title": "Purpose and Importance of the Sanctuary",
        "content": [
            "Ps 73:17 Until I went into the sanctuary of God; [then] understood I their end.",
            "..."
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Some other title",
        "content": [
            "...",
            {
                "title": "sub-sub-title",
                "content": [
                    "sub-sub-content"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
      {
         "title": "Some different title",
         "content": [
            "..."
         ]
      }
   ] 
}
```